# How to add eventListener highlight buttonLockup?

Tags: tvos, tvml, tvjs

I want add eventListener highlight buttonLockup with stackTemplate.
Can you guide to use this?
Thanks,

Comment: Post the sample of your TVML with the button as you construct it.

Answer (score 0):

The event system in TVJS is extremely similar to that in a web browser. After all, it's just JS and a DOM. [MDN's documentation on Event Handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) should be mostly relevant

To add an event listener to a specific button, just find that button (using ID or name or whatever), and use `addEventListener`.

```
var myButton = doc.getElementByName('buttonLockup')
var onSelect = function(ev) {
  console.log('Button selected!')
}
myButton.addEventListener('select', onSelect)
```

However, depending on your use case, I've found [Apple's approach in their sample apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/samplecode/TVMLCatalog/Listings/client_js_Presenter_js.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016505-client_js_Presenter_js-DontLinkElementID_6) to be quite useful. They rely on the fact that events bubble up to the root of the template, and just listen to them there. So for example:

```
// Given a TVML document has been presented with this somewhere in it
<buttonLockup action="doSomething">Do something</buttonLockup>

// When it's selected, doSomething
var globalOnSelect = function(ev) {
  var target = ev.target;
  var action = target.getAttribute('action')

  if (action === 'doSomething') {
    console.log('Do Something button selected');
    doSomething();
  }
}

doc.addEventListener('select', globalOnSelect);
```